# Pivoting data in SQL and returning multiple associated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has the following fields: user_id, tag, tag_certification_date, tag_review_date, and tag_expiration_date. Each user number can have multiple tags, and in that case the user will have multiple rows in the table. One for each tag. There are 5 possible tags A, B, C, D, E.

Example data

```
user_id   tag      tag_certification_date    tag_review_date    tag_expiration_date
-------   ----    -----------------------   -----------------   --------------------
001        A            2020-01-01              2020-06-01           2021-01-01
001        B            2020-02-01              2020-07-01           2021-08-01
001        C            2020-03-01              2020-08-01           2021-03-01
```

I have been able to use PIVOT to create a query that gets part of the way there but I'm having trouble including all of the date fields. I would like the query to return all the data for a user as a single row. So each tag and each tag's corresponding tag_certification_date, tag_review_date, and tag_expiration_date.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want:

```
select user_id,
       max(case when tag = 'A' then tag_certification_date end) as tag_certification_date_a,
       max(case when tag = 'A' then tag_review_date end) as tag_review_date_a,
       max(case when tag = 'A' then tag_expiration_date end) as tag_expiration_date_a,
       max(case when tag = 'B' then tag_certification_date end) as tag_certification_date_b,
       max(case when tag = 'B' then tag_review_date end) as tag_review_date_b,
       max(case when tag = 'B' then tag_expiration_date end) as tag_expiration_date_b,
       . . . 
from t
group by user_id
```